# Update dynamically generated price of two boxes with select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this work with the help of jQuery docs but not success so far.

I have two boxes `paynow` and `payfull` that has `0` initial value but I am filling these boxes dynamically (jQuery) with product prices.

Now I have to update these values further with select option to discount the price (multiply with `data-percent`). This is the HTML.

```
<select class="discount">
  <option data-percent="0">Select Discount Coupon</option>
  <option data-percent="5">ABCD</option>
  <option data-percent="10">EFGH</option>
  <option data-percent="15">IJKL</option>
</select>

<span class="price" id="paynow">$0.00</span>
<span class="price" id="payfull">$0.00</span>
```

**EDIT: jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // For Calculator
  function Cost_Calculator() {

    var Currency = '$';
    var messageHTML = 'Please contact us for a price.';

    function CostFilter(e) {
      return e;
    }

    //Calculate function
    function calculate() {

      //Blank!
      var CalSaveInfo = [];
      $('#cost_calc_custom-data, #cost_calc_breakdown').html('');

      //Calculate total
      var calCost = 0;
      var calculate_class = '.cost_calc_calculate';
      $('.cost_calc_active').each(function() {

        //Calculation
        calCost = calCost + parseFloat($(this).data('value'));

        //Add to list
        var optionName = $(this).attr('value');
        var appendName = '<span class="cost_calc_breakdown_item">' + optionName + '</span>';

        var optionCost = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var appendCost = '<span class="cost_calc_breakdown_price">' + Currency + optionCost + '</span>';

        if (optionCost != "0") {
          var appendItem = '<li>' + appendName + appendCost + '</li>';
        }

        //hidden data
        var appendPush = ' d1 ' + optionName + ' d2 d3 ' + optionCost + ' d4 ';

        $('#cost_calc_breakdown').append(appendItem);

        CalSaveInfo.push(appendPush);

      });

      //Limit to 2 decimal places
      calCost = calCost.toFixed(2);

      //Hook on the cost
      calCost = CostFilter(calCost);

      var CustomData = '#cost_calc_custom-data';
      $.each(CalSaveInfo, function(i, v) {
        $(CustomData).append(v);
      });

      //Update price
      if (isNaN(calCost)) {
        $('#paynow').html(messageHTML);
        $('#payfull').html(messageHTML);
        $('.addons-box').hide();
      } else {
        $('#paynow').html(Currency + calCost);
        $('#payfull').html(Currency + calCost);
        $('.addons-box').show();
      }

    }

    //Calculate on click
    $('.cost_calc_calculate').click(function() {

      if ($(this).hasClass('single')) {
        //Add cost_calc_active class
        var row = $(this).data('row');
        //Add class to this only
        $('.cost_calc_calculate').filter(function() {
          return $(this).data('row') == row;
        }).removeClass('cost_calc_active');
        $(this).addClass('cost_calc_active');
      } else {
        // Remove class if clicked
        if ($(this).hasClass('cost_calc_active')) {
          $(this).removeClass('cost_calc_active');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('cost_calc_active');
        }
      }

      //Select item
      var selectItem = $(this).data('select');
      var currentItem = $('.cost_calc_calculate[data-id="' + selectItem + '"]');
      var currentRow = currentItem.data('row');

      if (selectItem !== undefined) {
        if (!$('.cost_calc_calculate[data-row="' + currentRow + '"]').hasClass('cost_calc_active'))
          currentItem.addClass('cost_calc_active');
      }

      //Bring in totals & information
      $('#cost_calc_breakdown_container, #cost_calc_clear_calculation').fadeIn();
      $('.cost_calc_hide').hide();
      $('.cost_calc_calculate').each(function() {
        calculate();
      });

      return true;
    });

    $('#cost_calc_clear_calculation').click(function() {
      $('.cost_calc_active').removeClass('cost_calc_active');
      calculate();
      $('#cost_calc_breakdown').html('<p id="empty-breakdown">Nothing selected</p>');
      return true;
    });
  }

  //Run cost calculator
  Cost_Calculator();

});
```

Comment: You forgot to post your jQuery code.

Comment: I didn't post jQuery code because it is a custom developed function and I don't want to modify it. Let me know if it cannot be done without it. I will post it here.

Comment: Just posted jQuery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // get price from #paynow (just a number)
    var getPaynow = $('#paynow').text().match(/\d+/);
    // get price from #payfull (just a number)
    var getPayfull = $('#payfull').text().match(/\d+/);
    $('.discount').on('change', function(){
        // get data-percent from selected option
        var discount = parseFloat($(this).find('>option:selected').attr('data-percent'));
        //alert(discount +'///'+ getPaynow+'///'+ getPayfull);
        //update price for #paynow and #payfull
        $('#paynow').text('$'+parseFloat(getPaynow - (getPaynow * discount / 100)));
        $('#payfull').text('$'+parseFloat(getPayfull - (getPayfull * discount / 100)));
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/fugw8cex/10/)

in your code you can update prices after this part of code

```
//Update price
      if (isNaN(calCost)) {
        $('#paynow').html(messageHTML);
        $('#payfull').html(messageHTML);
        $('.addons-box').hide();
      } else {
        $('#paynow').html(Currency + calCost);
        $('#payfull').html(Currency + calCost);
        $('.addons-box').show();
      }
      //get price from #paynow (just a number)
      getPaynow = $('#paynow').text().match(/\d+/);
      // get price from #payfull (just a number)
      getPayfull = $('#payfull').text().match(/\d+/);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the price is different if I keep selecting 2 different options. It keeps reducing.

Comment: Can't we save initial pricing values at someplace and update prices based on those initial pricing values.

Comment: @Roberthue updated answer  just get prices before select change

Comment: It's not working. I always get `0` on any select option. I guess it's because both `paynow` and `payfull` have initial value `0` when page loads. The values of these boxes are updated (user) much later. But `getPaynow` and `getPayfull` are set to `0` on page load. If it's easier to modify jQuery function for this, I have posted the code in question.

Comment: @Roberthue you need to update getPaynow  and getPayfull  after they updated

Comment: That also did not work. Although I got it working by saving values on HTML dom. Thanks.

Comment: @Roberthue sorry for not work as expected .. but I glad to hear that your code works .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
var totalPayNowPrice=parseFloat($('#paynow').text());
var totalPayFullPrice=parseFloat($('#payfull').text());
$('.discount').on('change',function(){  
    if(parseInt($('.discount option:selected').attr('data-percent'))){

    $('#paynow').text((totalPayNowPrice*parseInt($('.discount option:selected').attr('data-percent')))+'$');

    $('#payfull').text((totalPayFullPrice*parseInt($('.discount option:selected').attr('data-percent')))+'$');
}
});
```

**Just put the $ sign in you spans after the numbers, in order to parse function would work.**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrfs9fos/2/)

**UPDATE**

From another point I think there is a better solution to use prototype and store you current prices in spans inside global variable, then you can use them wherever you want. Here the pseudo prototype for your use, if you`d like just customize it for you using:

```
function Test(){
    this.totalPayNowPrice=1;//the is 1 only for check code working
    this.totalPayFullPrice=1;
}
Test.prototype={

    init: function(){
        var scope=this;
        $('.discount').on('change',function(){  
          if(parseInt($('.discount option:selected').attr('data-percent'))){
            $('#paynow').text((scope.totalPayNowPrice*parseInt($('.discount option:selected').attr('data-percent')))+'$');

            $('#payfull').text((scope.totalPayFullPrice*parseInt($('.discount option:selected').attr('data-percent')))+'$');
         }
    },
   updatePaynowPrice:function(newPrice){
        this.totalPayNowPrice=totalPayNowPrice;
    },

   updatePayfullPrice:function(newPrice){
          this.totalPayFullPrice=totalPayNowPrice;
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Roberthue See my updated answer and working JSFIDDLE example

Comment: Kinda working but there is a bug. It keeps updating value if I keep selecting different options. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Can't we save initial pricing values at someplace and update prices based on those initial pricing values.

Comment: @Roberthue You are right. Please see my updated code . Also JSFIDDLE was updated.